# Website showing error when accessing it

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, cpanel

I installed wordpress on my website. Uploaded a nice premium theme for ecommerce. But when I try to access the website then it shows an error. An image of the error is shown below. What can cause this error? The website was working fine. I mean to say that there was a "Coming Soon" shown on the website when I used to go to my website url. But after I installed wordpress, it's showing this error. I installed wordpress in the root directory, i.e I kept the "in dir" field blank while installing wordpress. Moreover, I did only one more change except installing wordpress is that I changed my cpanel password. These are the only two things I did and the website shows this error. Help will be appreciated. 
Edit: I just tried to access my website on my phone and it is showing the website but on desktop, it takes to an error page: http://mysitename.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi rather than http://mysitename.com
[image: This error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is most probably cached on your computer/browser or you have DNS cache and it points your domain name to some other ip address then the correct one.

Try using a different browser. Try using a private navigation window from your browser (it works with Firefox, Chrome).

If you are using windows try deleting your dns cache by going to **Start -> Run -> cmd.exe** then type this command and press Enter:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```